# Deploying K8S cluster without default worker pool in IBM Cloud

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, terraform, ibm-cloud, terraform-provider-ibm

Good day to you.

I am implementing VPC and K8S modules for Terraform to deploy a complete virtual datacenter including compute resources in the IBM managed cloud. I would like to have full control of the worker pools attributes, like

name

flavor

zone

size

and therefore I would like to delete the default worker pool. This should ideally happen during the deployment by terraform.

Does anyone know, whether it is possible?

I tried to set the worker count to zero and define a specific worker pool, but this creates me a cluster with to worker pools and one worker in the default pool.

Best regards.
Jan

Answer (score 0):

@Jan-Hendrik Palic unfortunately, the IBM Cloud Kubernetes Service API does not support this scenario at the moment. Because Terraform uses the API, there is no way right now to create a cluster without the default worker pool.

Comment: Good day to you. 
I think, you are right. It isn't possible to create a Cluster with the WebUserInterface with out a default cluster, too (I assume, the WUI uses the same API). ,-) 
Well, does one know a workaround? 

Best, 
Jan